# What is a good CMS to use for Restful API documentation?

Tags: wordpress, api, content-management-system

I am designing API for my web service. Creating the Restful API is easy. What I am struggling now is with the documentation.

What would be a good CMS to use? Wordpress, Joomla or others?

Comment: Or is there any wordpress theme that is good for Restful API documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at mindtouch.com to write your documentation (wiki style). If you use Maven, you can use mavendoc for your documentation.